# Confirn marker to move on polyline only in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I like to know the correct approach to make my marker move on polyline only on drag Event by the user. Do i need to have all coordinates on which the line is drawn or some better way. I m currently using geolib/ turf to achive whether the marker is near the line or not by geolib.near line check. but now I need the marker to restrict its moves on polyline only in react native.

Web example:
jsfiddle.net/9ghvK/5/

thanks.